# move element with border-top down, while leaving border-top in place?

Tags: css

I have a vertical header with my logo and navigation, separated by a border. I'd like to keep the logo and border where they are while moving the navigation elements down 25px. How do I achieve this?

```
header {
    background: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 123px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 158px; 
}
header logo {
    margin-top: ;

}
header nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 158px;
}
header nav ul li {
    font-family: dalle;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

<header>
        <logo>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="whskytngfxtrt logo" height="139" width="158" /></a></li>
        </logo><!-- end logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="blog"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                <li id="work"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- end nav -->
    </header><!-- end header -->
```

Comment: FYI - custom tags can be a bad idea. `logo` is not a real HTML tag, and I'm not sure about modern browsers but I know in the past I tried something similar and had problems with IE. You should just use a `div`.

Comment: Ryan P is right. You could also add a `class` or `id` to the `div` to make it easier to target using css. And don't forget to accept a helpful answer! :)

Comment: @ryan- thanks for your input, i'll make the changes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `padding-top:25px` to `header nav`:

```
header nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 158px;
    padding-top:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in css:

```
header nav ul { margin-top:25px }
```